# Vue.js : Module parse failed: Unexpected token (121:25) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babel-loader

I getting the below error while running the vue.js project. This project was run without any problem but comes out when I installed the @wagmi/core module and import it.

```
<script>
import { connect } from '@wagmi/core'
import { optimism } from '@wagmi/core/chains'
import { InjectedConnector } from '@wagmi/core/connectors/injected'
export default {

}
</script>
```

And here is the error msg.

```
./node_modules/@wagmi/connectors/dist/chunk-YZRVUC6Y.js 121:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (121:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       return "MetaMask";
|   };
>   if (ethereum.providers?.length) {
|     const nameSet = /* @__PURE__ */ new Set();
|     let unknownCount = 1;
```

I have installed babel-loader and settle the module option on vue.config.js. Here is the code.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './web-dist'),
   configureWebpack: {
       module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.js$/,
              use: {
                 loader: 'babel-loader',
              },
            },
          ],
       },
   }
};
```

PS: This project don't have webpack.config.js. I added this babel-loader setting to vue.config.js.

Comment: can you share your babel config and package.json?